# Yarn and MapReduce help in java

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am currently wrapping my head around Hadoop and I cant figure out how do I import files that reside in hdfs ‘/data/nasdaq/dividends’ and manipulate them?

Answer (score 0):

I use apache phoenix in my project to do some task/query. https://phoenix.apache.org/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what is the difficulty you are facing, but here is a good place to get started https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html